# How to draw karaoke-like text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to display some text with javascript and highlight it like karaoke - i.e. after some time, additional symbols to be highlighted. If I would like to have it smooth enough (i.e. highlight one symbol partially), what should I do and how? Should I use HTML5 canvas? Don't know what to start with.

Comment: I found this.  You could build off of it.  http://jsfiddle.net/bPGZT/  It uses the same method that came to my mind when I read your description.

Comment: Thanks, @Ding. But it doesn't address the main question I've asked - it doesn't allow to highlight one symbol partially (for ex., only left half of symbol "A" should be red, when right half - still blue).

Comment: I've modified it quickly (and basically) as an example.  http://jsfiddle.net/bPGZT/202/

Comment: @Ding, ;) - it is symbol by symbol now, so not smooth enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using a gradient that's translated through your symbols:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,30,0);
gradient.addColorStop(0.00,'blue');
gradient.addColorStop(0.50,'red');
gradient.addColorStop(1.00,'blue');

ctx.font='36px verdana';
ctx.fillStyle=gradient;

var text='Sing along with Mitch';
var offset=0;
var offsetChange=1;
var textWidth=100;
var textWidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
var nextTime=0;
var delay=16*3;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  if(offset<textWidth){requestAnimationFrame(animate);}
  if(time<nextTime){return;}
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
  ctx.translate(offset,0);
  ctx.fillText(text,-offset,50);
  ctx.translate(-offset,0);
  offset+=offsetChange;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is almost what I need. Will learn now to make like real karaoke - i.e. keep left part of the text as red and right as blue.

Comment: I've just found that the easiest way to have karaoke-like style is to apply gradient like 0.00 - blue, 0.99 - blue, 1.00 - red. @markE, could you please clarify how `nextTime` and `delay` are used in your code? Looks like they are not used and could be deleted.

Comment: You are correct. `nextTime` and `delay` are not used and can be deleted. I was going to use them to regulate the speed of the gradient animation across the words, but I was so tired I went to bed instead. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I can not get it working with `ctx.textAlign = 'center';`, could you please help me there?

Comment: `textAlign=center` moves the positioning point of the text to the center of that text so all you have to do is adjust the text's X position by adding `textWidth/2`: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/e1zjmfn9/

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change the text position - still it is left-aligned. I've tried to use cw/2 as first parameter for translate(), but it doesn't help - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/e1zjmfn9/1/

Comment: Just add the text offset to the translate: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/e1zjmfn9/